# When I try to add permission with permissionOverwrites, code completely changes it

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hi Stackoverflow community

[image]

As you can see, **permissionOverwrites{}** is kinda collection. I'm trying to add new permission with the following string.

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.member.voice.channelID).overwritePermissions([
     {
         id: target, 
         allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.CONNECT]
     },
])
```

At the end of the day, it completely changes the collection, rather than adding to it. But I want to keep previous content and add only the target permission. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Discord.js has been updated to version 13, you'll now have to add the .set function to the overwritePermissions. It will look like this

```
message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.member.voice.channelID).permissionOverwrites.set([
     {
         id: target, 
         allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.CONNECT]
     },
])
```

Comment: I'm doing this for version 12, my host still doesn't support Node.js 16.6 and I can't update it yet.

Comment: @EgeCanKaraoğlu in that case try `message.member.voice.channel.permissionOverwrites.create(message.member, { CONNECT: true });`

Comment: No problem, good luck with the rest of your bot :)